# Visual Studio: PictureBox not showing the full image

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

During the use of the application the user stores away a picture to be used for comparison later.

When the image is retrieved from the database it does not render fully in the picture box as seen below. The correct image has been retrieved but only the top is visible.

[image: Incomplete image in the picturebox]

I have tried multiple different picture box settings and image types but the result is always the same. I have also reproduced the error in another project with the same code.

The code I use is below:

```
Dim b() As Byte
b = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar, Byte())
If b Is Not Nothing Then
       stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
       stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
       Dim image As Image = image.FromStream(stream)
       pictureBox.Image = image
End if
```

I cannot figure this out. Has anyone seen something like this before?
Thanks!

Comment: I faced the same problem some days ago. It was solved by setting doubleBuffered property of the form to true.

Comment: Thanks but I just tried that and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: sorry to say but this might be the solution. you have to delete the picturebox and add it again to your form. In some cases this works. or use any other control instead of picturebox. I think there might be something like custom picturebox. You might find it on google.

Comment: Or you might try to add the picture in a button if it works then there is a problem in your designing and if you get the same results then something in your code or database. or change the size of the image and try again.

Comment: I tried adding the image to the button and that failed too. So you are probably right, there must be a problem with the database or code. The datatype length in the database is limited to 4000, varbinary(4000). I wonder if this may be be problem. The image I am retrieving are very small though.

Answer (score 0):

Where you define **stream**? If you read the Image.FromStream method documentation it say:

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.
>
> The stream is reset to zero if this method is called successively with
>   the same stream.

Comment: The code in the OP is inside a try/catch block and an if statement. Stream is defined outside of these.